# Ionic Side menu with sub menu

Tags: html, mobile, menu, ionic-framework, submenu

Need to create test 1 2 3 4 belongs to the header menu of Test

How to create mobile Side menu with sub menu in ionic framework?

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item menu-close-keep-history href="#/app/profile" class="item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-home"></i> Test
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close-keep-history href="#/app/assignedtasks" class="item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-paper"></i>
        test 1
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close-keep-history href="#/app/requirements" class="item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-paper"></i>
        test 2
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close-keep-history href="#/app/machinery" class="item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-paper"></i>
        test 3
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close-keep-history href="#/app/chat" class="item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-people"></i>
        test 4
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item menu-close-keep-history href="#/app/settings" class="item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-gear"></i>
        Settings
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item  menu-close-keep-history href="#/app/logout" class="item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-locked"></i>
        Logout
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: hello, you will need to add <ion-nav-view name="anything"> inside manu.html after this line <ion-side-menu side="left"> and then manage this navigation in app.js and throughout your views, I am only having issue in going back to main menu from sub menu back button.